# submit_tag with disable_with does not get passed into params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working in rails 3. When I do something very simple like this:

```
<p><%= submit_tag 'Create' %></p>
```

I get the `commit: Create` key/value pair in my params hash in my action. However, as soon as I add a `disable_with`:

```
<p><%= submit_tag 'Create', :disable_with => 'Processing...' %></p>
```

I don't get the value of `commit`. The problem is, I would like to be able to switch on the value of the submit tag when I have multiple submit buttons. It seems that I can't do that when I have `:disable_with` set?

Answer (score 0):

It should be datat-disable-with.Try this

```
<p><%= submit_tag 'Create', data: {:disable_with => 'Processing...'} %></p>
```

Comment: I'm working in rails 3, not rails 4. This doesn't change the generated html.

Comment: Besides, the problem isn't that disable_with isn't working, it properly disables the button. The issue is that it doesn't submit the button value when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, with `:disable_with` the value of this attribute will be used as the value for the disabled submit button instead of the value initially set in the `submit_tag`.

Following excerpt from the [`submit_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag) documentation:

> :disable_with - Value of this parameter will be used as the value for
>   a disabled version of the submit button when the form is submitted.
>   This feature is provided by the unobtrusive JavaScript driver.

Comment: The thing is, it's not being set in my params hash at all. There is no key/value pair.

Comment: If you are not seeing this `key/value` in your `params` hash then it's likely related to `jquery_ujs`.  As a debugging step please also check your request via your browser's developer tool (network tab in chrome).

Comment: I'm not using jquery, I'm using prototype, and the reason I discovered (posted in the edit) is that since the button is disabled it's not getting submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here in case anyone needs this in the future:

The button isn't getting submitted with the rest of the form because it is disabled. (Which, admittedly, should have been obvious.) My solution is to create a `hidden_field_tag` that gets updated with javascript before the form gets submitted, but it feels a little inelegant.